# How to unit test part of a Workflow?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I intend to test only one sequence of a workflow (it is not a separate CodeActivity).
Is there a way I can invoke only the desired Sequence and pass in the required arguments?

Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is: no you can't.

At least not efficiently. You can do a bunch of thinks with the workflow's XAML. Extract the inner sequence comes to my mind but, please, don't do it!

What about if your sequence is using local variables assigned on the outer scope? That's just about one think that can go wrong while testing an isolated inner sequence.

Anyway, why would you want to do something like that? That's just like unit testing a method call which is inside another method. Either you call the outer method (the workflow itself) or you isolate the inner method (the sequence) to be able to test it.

**Edit:**

Ok, if you want to go along with that, and counting you've a XAML with that *huge workflow*, maybe you can get away with something like this:

Load your XAML to an activity:

```
var activity = ActivityXamlServices.Load("c:\hugeworkflow.xaml");
```

Having your serialized activity, and counting that you know where inner sequence is, search for it inside `activity`. Lets imagine that that sequence is inside another sequence (which is the workflow root):

```
var rootSequence = activity as Sequence;

var innerSequence = rootSequence
                    .Activities
                    .FirstOrDefault(a => a is Sequence) as Sequence;
```

Now you can execute the inner sequence like this:

```
var arguments = new Dictionary<string, object> 
{
    { "IntArgument", 10 },
    { "StringArgument", "hello world" }
};

WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(innerSequence, arguments);
```

How can you assert something from a sequence, I don't know.

Haven't tested any of this code so something might be missing but you get the idea.

Comment: I have a huge workflow, and based on conditions a sequence of activities (independent of others). Which is a viable unit of work and intend to test those without worrying about satisfying a flow of pre-conditions.

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do is split the workflow in several subworkflows.

So, what you can do is create an activity a put this sequence inside, and then replace it in the main workflow. After that you can test it separately.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, couldnt get that. How do you split the workflow? And how do you put sequence inside an activity?

Comment: if your workflow is... workflow.xaml

1- Create a new xaml activity (i.e. Sequence.xaml).
2- Copy and paste your sequence in this activity.
2- Add the necessary in out arguments
3- Drop the new activity instead of your sequence in workflow.xaml

Comment: Nops. Please provide more details.

Comment: You can create workflow activities, which provide you with a canvas, just like a normal workflow, except you can include these activities in your main workflow, just like any other activity (they'll be added to the toolbox in VS).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting` library from [codeplex](http://wf.codeplex.com/) to unit test your individual activities. [More documentation](http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting%20Overview&referringTitle=Home) and [example](http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20do%20I%20use%20Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting&referringTitle=Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting%20Overview) matching your scenario.

Comment: Thanks, the API seem to be useful. But I still couldn't find a way to invoke part (sequence) of a workflow using WorkflowInvoker/ApplicationTest. There is no sample for this scenario. Please suggest if there is a link.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly employ a technique to achieve this but it wouldn't be very straightforward. The idea will be to replace all other activities outside of this one sequence with mock activities and invoke the workflow using the Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting project.

This link [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2010/09/24/how-to-unit-test-workflows-mocking-activities.aspx) explains what I mean

Out of curiosity given that the SOLID principles heavily advocate Interface Segregation and Single Responsibility, do you not see any merit into isolating those segments of your workflow which you call an atomic unit (and hence would like to test independently) into separate activities or children workflows?